# Loop in Jade (currently known as "Pug") template engine

Tags: javascript, for-loop, pug, express

I want to use a simple loop like `for(int i=0; i<10; i++){}`.

How do I use it in the Jade engine? I'm working with Node.js and use the expressjs framework.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

for example:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  li= array[i]
- }
```

you may see https://github.com/visionmedia/jade for detailed document.

Comment: hi qiao, I have a problem in here : [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730255/how-to-get-schema-of-mongoose-database-which-defined-in-another-model/8730351#8730351),
I resolved by way of <strong>alessioalex</strong>, but now i have new problem:
If with my database structure like that, then 1 album i can store many songs, is that right?
And why in app.js do: 
`var Album = db.model('Album'); var album = new Album(); album.songs.push({_id:'4f046b3bf71f5ed522000002'});` <br/> and I get error Cannot call method 'call' of undefined <br/> how do i store to right?

Comment: It's probably because the `SongSchema` is not defined in `album.js`.

Comment: i have an array x,console.log(x, x.length); shows me this:
[{name:a,done:true},{name:c}]   0       is that normal? what i'm missing

Answer (score 78):

Using node I have a collection of stuff `@stuff` and access it like this:

```
- each stuff in stuffs
  p
    = stuff.sentence
```

Comment: this is the canonical way to do this according to http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/. Also, you don't actually need the `-` in front of the `each` on the first line either

Comment: Pug errors if you have a - (dash) in front of each.

Comment: Could you explain `@stuff`? Why is there an `@` at the beginning?

Answer (score 35):

An unusual but pretty way of doing it

**Without index**:

```
each _ in Array(5)
  = 'a'
```

Will print: `aaaaa`

**With index**:

```
each _, i in Array(5)
  = i
```

Will print: `01234`

**Notes**: In the examples above, I have assigned the `val` parameter of jade's `each` iteration syntax to `_` because it is required, but will always return `undefined`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a very simple `jade` file that have a loop in it. Jade is very sensitive about white space. After loop definition line (`for`) you should give an indent(tab) to stuff that want to go inside the loop. You can do this without `{}`:

```
- var arr=['one', 'two', 'three'];
- var s = 'string';
doctype html
html
    head
    body
        section= s
        - for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
            div= arr[i]
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to remove whitespace between elements generated in this way?

Comment: @vsync A hack would be to use `span` instead of `div`

Comment: I mean generally. there would always be a white space between elements this way because there is a `new line` cause by the way jade syntax works.

Answer (score 10):

Just adding another possibility as it might help someone that's trying to both iterate over an array AND maintain a count. For example, the code below goes through an array named `items` and only displays the first 3 items. Notice that the `each` and the `if` are native jade and don't need a hyphen.

```
ul
  - var count = 0;
  each item in items
    if count < 3
      li= item.name
    - count++;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this: `- count++;`

Answer (score 6):

You could also speed things up with a `while` loop (see here: http://jsperf.com/javascript-while-vs-for-loops). Also much more terse and legible IMHO:

```
i = 10
while(i--)
    //- iterate here
    div= i
```

Comment: Yea, but your while loop starts with 10 and works its way down. This adds the items to the DOM in reverse order. You probably don't want that.

Comment: @PhillipBurch it can be reversed too: `var i = 0; while (i++ < 10) console.log(i-1) //=> 0123456789`

Answer (score -2):

Pug (renamed from 'Jade') is a templating engine for full stack web app development. It provides a neat and clean syntax for writing HTML and maintains strict whitespace indentation (like Python). It has been implemented with JavaScript APIs. The language mainly supports two iteration constructs: each and while. 'for' can be used instead 'each'. Kindly consult the language reference here:

https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Here is one of my snippets:
[each/for iteration in pug_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyRNV.jpg)