# How to get Schema of mongoose database which defined in another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This is my folder structure:

```
+-- express_example
|---- app.js
|---- models
|-------- songs.js
|-------- albums.js
|---- and another files of expressjs
```

My code in file songs.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var SongSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, default: 'songname'}
, link: {type: String, default: './data/train.mp3'}
, date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
, position: {type: Number, default: 0}
, weekOnChart: {type: Number, default: 0}
, listend: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Song', SongSchema);
```

And here is my code in file albums.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema
, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, default: 'songname'}
, thumbnail: {type:String, default: './images/U1.jpg'}
, date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
, songs: [SongSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
```

How can I make albums.js know **SongSchema** to be defined AlbumSchema

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can get models defined elsewhere directly with Mongoose:

```
require('mongoose').model(name_of_model)
```

To get the schema in your example in albums.js you can do this:

```
var SongSchema = require('mongoose').model('Song').schema
```

Comment: If with my database structure like that, then 1 album i can store many song, is that right? 
<br/> And why in app.js do: 
<br/> `var Album = db.model('Album');
var album = new Album();
album.songs.push({_id:'4f046b3bf71f5ed522000002'});` 
<br/> and I get error `Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`
<br/> how do i store to right?

Comment: I was getting the exact same thing. Ended up fixing it by using `var SongSchema = require('mongoose').model('Song').schema` instead (i.e. I added `.schema` to grab the schema of the model specifically).

Comment: So how does this work when there are multiple connections? Which one does it use?

Answer (score 28):

To get the schema from a registered Mongoose model, you need to access the schema specifically:

```
var SongSchema = require('mongoose').model('Song').schema;
```

Answer (score 6):

For others not as familiar with the deeper aspects of how Mongoose works, the existing answers can be confusing.

Here's a **generalized implementation** example of importing a *schema* from another file that is accessible to a wider audience coming from a more general context.

```
const modelSchema = require('./model.js').model('Model').schema
```

Here's a modified version for the **specific case** in the question (this would be used *inside* albums.js).

```
const SongSchema = require('./songs.js').model('Song').schema
```

From this, I can see that you first access and require the file how one would normally go about requiring a model, except in this case you now specifically access the schema of that model.

Other answers require mongoose *within* the variable declaration and that goes against the commonly found example of requiring mongoose before through declaring a variable such as `const mongoose = require('mongoose');` and then using mongoose like that. Such a use case was not accessible knowledge-wise to me.

---

#### Alternative option

You can require *just the model* like you normally would and then refer to the schema through the Model's schema property.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// bring in Song model
const Song = require('./songs.js');

const AlbumSchema = new Schema({
    // access built in schema property of a model
    songs: [Song.schema]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var SongSchema = require('mongoose').model('Song').schema;
```

The above line of code in your `albums.js` will surely work.

Comment: @Prasad Jadhav : Thanks for improvements

Comment: that won't work, as it doesn't return the schema but the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
"songs" : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Song', required: true}]
```

Comment: He probably needs the schema for embedding not refrencing