# How can I get the full schema definition of a Mongoose collection?

Tags: mongoose

Including properties, types, etc? What I'm looking to get, in essence:

```
{
    label: {
        type: "String",
        required: true
    },
    published: {
        type: "Boolean",
        default: true
    }
}
```

Calling `mongoose.model('someModel').schema.paths` only returns the property type for `String`, `Number`, and `ObjectId`, all others are `undefined`. When I read up on this in the GitHub issue queue it seemed that this info (the `schema.paths[path].instance` property) was internal and shouldn't even be used in the first place.

If that's the case, how can one get the schema definition programmatically?

Related questions that don't answer this:

- [How to get Schema of mongoose database which defined in another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730255/how-to-get-schema-of-mongoose-database-which-defined-in-another-model)
- [getting schema attributes from Mongoose Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035297/getting-schema-attributes-from-mongoose-model)

Related GitHub issue:

- https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1938

Comment: The `tree` property on the schema looks pretty close. You could also just save off your original schema definition object.  What are you ultimately trying to do with this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got merged into Mongoose 4.0.0: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1938