# How to retrieve schema from a mongoose collection?

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

using this line :

```
var collection = mongoose.connection.db.collection("users");
```

I get users s collection, now i need to get the schema from that collection ?
Is there a way to do this? thank you.

> PS: I dont have any models

Comment: For **defined** model, you can get it. refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730255/how-to-get-schema-of-mongoose-database-which-defined-in-another-model

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have any models, I'm afraid this can't be done.

the schema is the structural representation of the document, not the collection. You can use the schema (via the model) to enforce that any document added to the collection match some structure, but there's nothing that prevents you from inserting into this collection a different document without this model, that will not match the criteria

so the schema does not live in the DB, it is a part of the mongoose module, and lives in the code. and the way to access it is through the model only

Comment: thank you, i ended up using the collection to create my queries with mongoose.