# Rendering Jade template via AJAX and trying to pass/access data separate from the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I am rendering a Jade template on an ajax call via res.render with Express. Problem is I want to pass back some JSON vars or Javascript objects along with the HTML.

Is this possible in an elegant way or at all? I know I can pass a script tag along with the HTML but I'm not sure how I can access those values directly within the 'data' response.

Example here:

```
- var someNumber = 89
h1 Hello World
li #{someNumber}
```

Normally in a res.render() of this template on an ajax call you would get back

```
<h1> Hello Wolrd </h1>
<li> 89 </li>
```

All in HTML format.

How do I access one of the HTML nodes in the callback? Ideally with a jQuery selector, such as $('h1 li'). I need access to the number in the call back but it doesn't seem to be grabbing it. I'm thinking listener or adding a delay or maybe I need to assign it to a string and parse it out.

Comment: I didn't understand. Could you please post the code you are using?

Comment: @MarkLinus updated to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand the question. However, to pass JSON direct to the browser via Jade. In your route logic you need something like:

```
    res.render "test",
    title: "Test"
    debugJson: {
      'Read Folder Result' : result, 
      'HTTP' : {
        'Req URL' : req.url,
        'Req Query' : req.query,
        'Req User' : req.user,
        'Req Headers' : req.headers,
        'Req' : req,
        'Res' : res
      }
    }
```

(Sorry, that is in CoffeeScript rather than JS)

And in your Jade template, you need to have something like (in a script):

```
var myJson = !{JSON.stringify(debugJson)};
```

which will pass the JSON straight into the script. If you want it direct into the DOM, something like:

```
#debug !{JSON.stringify(debugJson)}
```

Which will dump it into a div.

If you just want to process it in the Jade template however, you can simply use a loop in Jade. See this [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine) for how to do that.

Comment: Alright, so either way I have to pass it as a script var. That's what I was trying to avoid having to do. Maybe multiple requests will be a better solution but I'm afraid not.

Comment: And honestly the best way to pass JSON to your browser is not this way at all. Just use res.json() if you just need that piece.