# Render array in Jade

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pug

I passed an array to jade

```
router.get('/index', function(req, res){
    var users = ["A","B","C"];  
    res.render('index', {user: users})
});
```

//what i get in jade

```
li #{user}
<li>a,b,c</li>                               

li #(user[0])
<li>a</li>
```

How can i get this instead without having to write user[0], user[1], user[2]?

```
<li>A</li> 
<li>B</li> 
<li>C</li>
```

I have tried following, but i had error.

each item in #{user}
each item in user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `each` [(see docs)](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

```
ul
  each user in users
    li= user
```

And you should change your rendering call to:

```
res.render('index', {users: users})
//                       ^ added this character
```

Since you have an array of `user` objects, you should call it `users`. That way you can map `user`, singular, to the value of each user.

Comment: Hi, i got error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". users is not defined

Comment: See my edit. Obviously you need to reference the variable you pass to the template.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/) for documentation.

```
ul                     // create ul list tag
  each u in user       // start loop
    li= u              // create li tag and assign innerHTML to array item value
```

Comment: Hi, i got error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". users is not defined

Comment: I updated the answer. Your view has `user`, not `users`

Answer (score -2):

You can also use javascript if the array is less amenable to the native each (already posted as an answer).

`- for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
  li= users[i]
- }`

See: [Loop in Jade (currently known as "Pug") template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine)

Comment: Your loop is going 1..10 will throw an exception for out of bounds in many cases.