# How to do a for loop with Jade in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, express, pug

I'm new to Node.js/Express/Jade and I can't figure how to do a for-loop. I searched on the web but didn't find the answer. Also, the jade documentation is nearly empty.

Here is what I want to do:

when I'm in the url `/count/:number`, I want to count from 0 to that number and display the number. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
h1 I'm gonna count to  #{number}

  script(type='text/javascript')
    for(i = 0, i < number; i++) {
      p #{i}
    }
```

I got this error: `Duplicate attribute "i" is not allowed.`
I already try this solution but it didn't work:
[Loop in Jade (currently known as "Pug") template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine?lq=1)

I don't understand too why is there '-' before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop in Jade engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine)

Comment: From personal experience, even though Jade seems appealing at first, I suggest you don't spend too much time figuring everything out on Jade. There were instances (like a year ago) where one could not do everything in the template. Plus, it is going to be much easier to define some divs and then have a javascript file that manipulates that div dynamically. Just update your DOM, delegate your functions and call them correctly and you will finish in much shorter time. Just my 2 cents.