# Loop in jade with curly brackets

Tags: html, node.js, for-loop, pug

I am really struggling to master Jade. I want to do something very very simple: print out "some text" 3 times. I have a mixin function:

```
mixin outputText()
- for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    span some text
```

This works fine. Now when I try to output more text on a second line, so first I need to use {} as later there will now be 2 `spans` on 2 different lines. So first, surrounding current function with curly brackets:

```
- for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    span some text
- }
```

But I get the error: `unexpected token "indent"`

I have seen someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728762/1246159) doing the EXACT same thing. Why wont it work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I recommend iteration? If you are working with values this is perfect:

```
ul
    each val, index in ['zero', 'one', 'two']
        li= val
        li= Some Text
```

However if you are simply looking to repeat lines over you could do this:

```
ul
    while n < 4
        li= Sometext
```

[A handy guide by Jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it. When your function have surrounded with curly brackets, you don't append indent within for-loop code

```
- for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
  span some hello
- }
```

Comment: still getting unexpected token "indent"