# How to make a while loop with multiple variables?

Tags: pug

How to make a while loop with multiple variables?

```
ul
    while i++ < 10
        item = .container: img(src="images/", alt="")
        li(item)/
```

What you need to do to make this code work? Make it like in the code below.

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="container"> </div><img src="" alt="">
    <li><div class="container"> </div><img src="" alt="">
</ul>
```

**UPD: 0.0.1**

This code -

```
ul
  - for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    - var item = 5
    li item
```

compiled in -

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

And I need -

```
<ul>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need a for or for each loop?

Comment: @Cludch: You cannot assign a variable to a variable in a loop.

Comment: Updated the answer, should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use some kind of a for loop from JavaScript.

```
ul
    - for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        item = .container: img(src="images/", alt="")
        li(item)/
    - }
```

Source: [Loop in Jade (currently known as "Pug") template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine)

For your updated code:

Either use `li #{item}` or `li= item`. E.g.

```
ul
    - for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        - var item = 5
        li= item
    - }
```

Comment: No, it does not work... you Can check yourself in the online interpreter. http://jade-lang.com/