# Creating for loop in template node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am usind node.js(expess) and pugs template. On my server i have

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.get('/users' , function( req , res){
       users.findAll().then(function(users){  //retrieve informations about users
             res.render('users_list' , users:users)
       })
})
```

the users_list template looks like

```
html
  head
    title="Users"
  body
    h1 'List of users'
    #container
```

and after container i would like to create div element for every user , how can i achieve it using pug templates? Does it support for loops or can a script included access arguments that are passed into template?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop in Jade engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine)

Comment: @ZimSystem Its not exactly only about loops , i would like to know the way how to pass variable from server there and use it in javascript

Comment: A script can access `attributes` that are passed into html elements, for example: `<div id="user-1" data-age="18"></div>`

Comment: I am not talking about attributes.

Comment: I am, you're asking a way to pass variables from the server to use in javascript, this is a way, and a generally accepted one as well, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
html
  head
    title="Users"
  body
    h1 'List of users'
    #container
      - for user in users
        div#user= user.email
```

See: [Loop in Jade engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-engine) for more details.