# How to make for each loop in jade in node.js

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

I want to pass an array to `create.jade` in `Select` but it can not show `courses` in `dropdown`. Here is the code.

```
subjectServices.create = function (req, res) {
    return courseStorage.list()
     .then(courses => {
        console.log("aa", courses)
        // let course = courses
        res.render('../views/subjects/create', {course: courses});
     })
};
```

In `console` it shows the courses but in `select dropdown` it can not show any courses. I don not know why it can not show. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Here is the code of `create.jade`.

```
include ../layout/main

block content
style(type='text/css').
  .main-header .navbar{
  background-color: #3c8dbc;
  }
title Admin Dashboard
.wrapper
  .content-wrapper
    body
      .container
        h3
          //- a(href='/employees') Employee List
          a.btn.btn-primary(href="/subjects")  Subject List
        h1 Create New Subject
        form.form-horizontal(action='/subjects/save', method='post')
          .form-group
            .col-md-1
              label(for='subjectName') Subject Name*
            .col-lg-10
              input#subjectName.form-control(type='text', name='subjectName', placeholder='Subject Name')
          .form-group
            .col-md-1
              label(for='courseSelectbox') Choose Course*
              select#courseSelectbox.form-control(name='course')
              if courses != null && courses.length > 0
                for course in courses
                    option(value='') --Select One--
                    option(value='#{courses._id}') #{ courses.name }
          br
          br
          button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Create
```

Comment: `- course.forEach(function(item) {
  li= item
- })` or in your case i think it should be `option(value='#{course._id}')` not `option(value='#{courses._id}')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop in Jade (currently known as "Pug") template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728637/loop-in-jade-currently-known-as-pug-template-engine)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the local you're passing to your Pug template is `course`, not `courses`. Try changing it to `courses` instead:

```
res.render('../views/subjects/create', {courses: courses});
```

Then in the Pug loop, use the singular to access individual properties:

```
for course in courses
    option(value='#{course._id}') #{course.name}
```